# SKStoreReviewController requestReview doesn't show the review prompt when debugging on Xcode 14.3.1, macOS 13.6

Tags: swift, objective-c, xcode, macos, storekit

[SKStoreReviewController requestReview] doesn't show the review prompt when debugging on Xcode 14.3.1, macOS 13.6. Why is that? Is it a known bug?

Comment: Did you request on a real device? According to Apple document, the ratings and review popup only show up maximum of 3 times a year.

Comment: Yes, I did testing on real Mac

Comment: Check this [Document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skstorereviewcontroller/3566727-requestreview), on Discussion section

Comment: It mentioned: When your app calls this method while it’s in development mode, StoreKit always displays the rating and review request view, so you can test the user interface and experience.

Comment: Having exactly the same issue in Xcode 15.0.1 on macOS 13.6.1. When running my MacOS app in debug from Xcode the review prompt never shows. Tried @Environmen(.\requestReview) and SKStoreReviewController.requestReview(). Again, developing and testing on real Mac. Both debug builds from Xcode and development test from archive. According to the documentation, in development / debug builds it should always present the rating prompt. Making development around this very difficult.